# Trying to restrict method usage options

Tags: c#

I have wrapping that looks like following:

```
public static void DoThing(Action T)
{
    //Some code here
    T();
    //Some more code here
}
```

It's used to call static methods from static class like this:

```
DoThing(()=>{
    SomeStaticClass.SomeStaticMethod();
});
```

I was thinking about adding boolean flag to SomeStaticClass, but concurrency is a concern.

Is there any good way to make it so that when method is called without DoThing, it throws an exception or alerts me in some other way?

Comment: I don't think, that this is possible or even a good idea. Maybe you can tell us more about your situation, so that we can understand your problem better.

Comment: `T` is a *really* bad name for a parameter of type `Action`.  It's the wrong case for a parameter, doesn't describe what that parameter is, and is likely to be confused with the common convention of using `T` for a generic type argument.  `action` would be a better name, or `thingToDo` or something dependant on what that specific thing should be doing (if there is such a thing).

Comment: A bad way could be this at the start of SomeStaticMethod: `if (!"DoThing".Equals(new StackTrace().GetFrame(2).GetMethod().Name)) throw new InvalidOperationException();`

Comment: @Servy `DoThing()`, `SomeStaticClass`, and `SomeStaticMethod()` aren't so hot either. I think he's substituting arbitrary names for the real ones here.